Microsoft Entra - Login Fails After Multiple Redirects
I am trying to follow along the quick start tutorial, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-web-app-dotnet-core-sign-in.
I have built the app exactly as they have specified, multiple times. I have the general live.com account and my organization office account. I have created the app registration in both of these inside the Entra Admin Dashboard, and multiple times, with the creation and configuring the settings. I have set the callback path, "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc", and updated the exact URL in the identity settings in the entra app registration, with the applicationUrl, without any mistakes or extra spaces or slashes or anything.
Each time, the same thing happens.

The login starts
the login goes through the flow (enter password, 2FA code, all that is fine)
then, it enters some kind of a loop, which seems to 'retry', and eventually comes back to the login page, saying, 'unable to login' and shows me the sign in page again.
in the browser console, there is something about 'CORP' being blocked, and i don't know if that is the issue.
The browser after login URL has the client id, other values, the redirect URL as per the app settings and app registration settings. everything seems to match.

I have tested in 3 browsers, edge, chrome, firefox. Tried both, regular mode and private browsing mode.
When I created the app from the live.com entra dashboard, I only used my live.com account as there is no option to create new users. When I created the app from the office 365 entra dashboard, I tested with multiple user accounts, both regular and dummy accounts. In all these accounts, and different domains and different app registrations, the output is the same.
multiple redirects, login flow completes, but, does not finish redirection and just comes back to the login page.
